# Elementor says - "Sorry, the content area was not found in your page. " while using custom shortcode

Tags: wordpress, shortcode, elementor

I am using default theme of Elementor Plugin. Plugin is very nice but I am facing issue while using my custom shortcode in page. It shows “Sorry, the content area was not found in your page. You must call
the_content function in the current template, in order for Elementor to work on this page.”
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xBHV.png

To solve this error, I have added `<?php the_content(); ?>` in my custom shortcode but it shows the same error.
I have also tried by creating a custom template, but the result is same.

So please help me to solve this error. Any suggestions are acceptable.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably your shortcode function changes the post query.
try adding `wp_reset_query();` before the function closes.